# Detecting jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I detect whether or not an input box is currently a jQuery UI autocomplete?  There doesn't seem to be a native method for this, but I'm hoping there is something simple like this:

```
if ($("#q").autocomplete)
{
  //Do something
}
```

That conditional, however, seems to always return true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if ($("#q").hasClass("ac_input")) {
    // do something
}
```

**UPDATE**

The class name in the JQuery UI autocomplete widget is now 'ui-autocomplete-input' so that code would be:

```
if ($("#q").hasClass("ui-autocomplete-input")) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also find the autocomplete behavior attached to an input element by following line of code:

```
if ($('Selector').data('autocomplete')) {
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If the autocomplete jquery UI plugin is already included for the page and you just want to check to see if a particular (input) element has been setup with autocomplete function, you can use the **official API method** as shown below:

```
if ($("#q").autocomplete("instance")) {
    console.log("autocomplete already setup for #q");
} else {
    console.log("NO autocomplete for #q");
}
```

More details can be found at http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-instance

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
if( $.isFunction( $.fn.autocomplete ) ){ }
```

.isFunction is part of the jQuery lib. (cite: [http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/....isFunction](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4&fn=jQuery.isFunction))

Comment: This merely checks if `autocomplete` exists as a function, which means the autocomplete plugin is loaded into memory.  But that is not what the question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's true because once you've included the autocomplete js, every $() object now has a autocomplete() method defined (in case you want to activate autocomplete for those elements).  Your if() is just saying that that function is not null.

I, unfortunately don't have a system where I can check this (left the laptop home today), but I believe autocomplete adds a css class name to the elements it's using.  You could look for that.