# Checking if jQuery UI autocomplete exists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I check if the **jQuery autocomplete** is applied to a selector ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting jQuery UI autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254765/detecting-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery autocomplete automatically adds a css class name **"ui-autocomplete-input"** to the elements it is using. You could look for those elements.